# dropdown menu in my chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I buil an google-chrome-extension and now want to add a dropdown menu.
My problem is that when I click on of my menu-points its open a new chrome tab with my popup.html and don't reload it.
I tried this and the way with `<ul>` and `<li>`.

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a id="menu1" href="#">menu1</a>
            <a id="menu2" href="#">menu2</a>
            <a id="menu3" href="#">menu3</a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I want to use it to run some JavaScript after select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen to `click` event for `a` tag and add `e.preventDefault()` to disable browser default behavior.

```
$(".dropdown-content a").click(function(e) {
    // your logic here
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried it and wrote just for testing document.write("test"); for logic. Now it does not open a new tab and reload my popup. But my hole html is gone. Just "test" standing there.

Comment: @Paili, please be aware `document.write` is used to write a string of text ot a document stream, and when click event is executed, the document has been loaded(closed), write on a closed document will automatically call `document.open`, which will clear the document. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Used now $("#card").append('<p>new element!</p>'); and it worked for me.

Comment: @Paili, you could also use `console.log` to output something, and open console window for popup page by right-clicking the icon and select 'inspect elements'